# Detect Input Focus Using Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an auto-complete list that appears as you type, but disappears when you click elsewhere on the document. How do I detect that a form input is focused using Angular 2. Angular 1 has ng-focus, but I don't think Angular 2 supports that anymore.

```
<input id="search-box" type="search" class="form-control [(ngModel)]=query (keyup)=filter()>
    <div id="search-autocomplete" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0">
        <ul *ngFor="#item of filteredList" >
            <li > <a (click)="select(item)">{{item}}</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

By the way, I used this tutorial as [guidance](http://4dev.tech/2016/03/tutorial-creating-an-angular2-autocomplete/).

Answer (score 143, accepted):

There are `focus` and `blur` events:

```
<input (blur)="onBlur()" (focus)="onFocus()">
```

Answer (score 24):

For those using `@angular/material`, you can get a reference to the `MatInput` instance which implements `MatFormFieldControl` interface exposing a nice `focused` property.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput #searchInput="matInput" type="text" />
  <mat-icon matPrefix svgIcon="filter" [color]="searchInput.focused ? 'primary' : ''"></mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Pretty sweet!  Nice to know we can dynamically change the display like that.

Comment: what for those who are not using angular material? I've a same scenario but the input field of mine is not a `matInput`

Answer (score 4):

You could also use FocusMonitor from @angular/cdk.

https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control#focused

```js
focused = false;

constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private fm: FocusMonitor, private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
  ...
  fm.monitor(elRef.nativeElement, true).subscribe(origin => {
    this.focused = !!origin;
    this.stateChanges.next();
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  ...
  this.fm.stopMonitoring(this.elRef.nativeElement);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the ngControl directive to track change-state and validity of form fields.

```
<input type="text" ngControl="name" />
```

The NgControl directive updates the control with three classes that reflect the state.

State: Control has been visited

```
ng-touched
ng-untouched
```

State: Control's value has changed

```
ng-dirty
ng-pristine
```

State: Control's value is valid

```
ng- valid
ng- invalid
```

Comment: Helpful, but doesn't seem to offer focus state.

Comment: helpful but the question is on focused state. FormControl doesnt provide focused state explicitly.