# How to check if an input field is in focus in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-forms

I have a form and I want to know if any of the input fields in the form are focused or not?

I read the '**NgForm**' documentation but didn't find anything related to '**focus**'.

I found **touched** but it doesn't satisfy needs.

Comment: You'll have to use the DOM to do that.

Comment: You can use `focus` and `blur` events, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755240/detect-input-focus-using-angular-2

Answer (score 30):

You can use the focus and blur events, to track as fields gain or lose focus :

```
<input (focus)="onFocus()" (blur)="onBlur()">
```

There are also javascript’s own  :

document.hasFocus() : whether the document or any element inside the document has focus.

document.activeElement : Property containing which element currently has focus.

Answer (score 15):

At a time you can have one focused input. Probably the easiest way would be to use focus event and pass element to your component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    <input type="text "(focus)="onFocus($event)" (blur)="onFocus()" />
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedElement: any;
  onFocus(event) {
    if(event){
       this.selectedElement = event.target;
    } else {
       this.selectedElement = null; 
    }
  }
}
```

Other option would be to write directive to set specific class on focus

```
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[trackFocus]'
})
export class TrackFocusDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.my-focused-element') isFocused: boolean;
  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event']) onFocus(e) {
    this.isFocused = true;
  }
  @HostListener('blur', ['$event']) onblur(e) {
    this.isFocused = false;
  }
}
```

So now you can do this

```
<input type="text"  trackFocus/>
```